# Interaction with odd number of fermionic fields?

Tags: field-theory, fermions, interactions, grassmann-numbers, superalgebra

Can there exist an interacting part of the Hamiltonian with odd number of fermionic operators? In other words, can we have a vertex which couples an odd number of fermions (there can also be 1, 2, or arbitrary number of bosons)?

It seems that none of the theories I know of satisfy this condition: QED, $\phi^4$, $\phi^3$, ordinary Coulomb gas, BCS hamiltonian ...

Does there exist some conservation law or symmetry restriction that forbid this?

Comment: The Hamiltonian must be Hermitian and what you suggest won't be.

Comment: We can make this Hermitian, for example: $H_{int} = (c+c^{\dagger})b^{\dagger}b$ where $c$ corresponds to fermions and $b$ to bosons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, in conventional formulations the action and the Hamiltonian should be Grassmann-even. E.g. the Hamiltonian is supposed to measure energy, which is an ordinary number, not a [Grassmann-number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmann_number). So all their terms (in particular their interaction terms) should contain an even number of Grassmann-odd fields$^1$.

--

$^1$ In case of superfields, we're here referring to their component formulation.